# Can PayPal Here be used if there is no cell signal?

Tags: paypal

I'm looking at the Square and PayPal Here as a credit card processing platform for a POS operation. It will be used in various locations around the country and it's possible that at times it will need to be used when there is no cell signal.

The Square has a clearly documented Offline Mode available, but I can't seem to find anything on this for PayPal Here. Can PayPal Here be used if there is no cell signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Here has no offline mode yet.